# Merge rows so whole sheet shows "text" and "url" one under the other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: See attached image]There are a bunch of highlighted yellow text. I want to **merge** rows e.g. 6, 7, 8 and 9 into 6. Similarly 17 & 18 into 17. So and so forth

So the final output I want is

```
Text
URL
Text
URL
Text
URL
```

Note: 
1. This is sample file but it could have **hundreds** of rows with uneven rows to be merged.

-------- Update -------
I have used the following formula and then filter so only "Comments" shows then manually go through row and merge manually. I want an automatic solution.

```
  =MOD(ROW(),2)
```

Comment: Please do not include external file links in your question. Instead, include the relevant code and/or screenshots of the data in your question.

Comment: Thank you, braX. Appreciate clarification. In order to make it easy to help, I thought of giving reference. What is the best way to explain my above problem? Is anything I can do to improve?

Comment: Can you update your question with your attempt at solving this issue and also the logic behind the merge?

Comment: I have updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain that there are MANY ways to do this kind of thing.  This is as elegant as I can make it.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Range("A" & lngRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        If Range("A" & lngRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And Range("A" & lngRow - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Range("A" & lngRow - 1) = Range("A" & lngRow - 1) & vbCrLf & Range("A" & lngRow)
            Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Finally, assuming you do NOT have colored cells, use the code below.

```
Sub MacroUpdate()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim LResult As String
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Left(Range("A" & lngRow), 4) <> "http" Then
        If Left(Range("A" & lngRow), 4) <> "http" And Left(Range("A" & lngRow - 1), 4) <> "http" Then
            Range("A" & lngRow - 1) = Range("A" & lngRow - 1) & vbCrLf & Range("A" & lngRow)
            Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ash, It works like a charm. I can definitely use your work. However, I am sorry if I was unclear. In the screenshot, I have just highlighted text to give more clarity to the problem. But in actual case it would be just plain.  Now if we assume it's not color highlighted then how it works? AGAIN PROBLEM: "Assume there are hundreds of rows with either "text" or "URL". Now sometimes there are multiple "text" rows i.e. 2, 3, 4, 5 and then "URL". I want to merge multiple text rows so final output is Text, URL, Text, URL. How to make it work? Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Ok, I thought you were doing the work based on the colors of the cells.  Ok, I just added a new script.  That last one should do what you want.  Please up-vote my answer if it helps you.

Comment: Hi ASH, You are simply superb. It works perfectly. Very elegantly and smoothly. I have Up-vote your answer. Thanks a million again.